# Terraform import of ec2_instance is in replaced mode during terraform plan

Tags: terraform

I am trying to map existing resources into terraform. I mapped most of the ec2_instances in terraform. After running terraform plan, I see all of ec2_instances is in "update in-place" (which is good) except two of the instances which are in "replaced" mode (not desired as it will drop and recreate the 2 ec2_instances). After checking the plan for these two instances, I found out the below messages:

```
      ~ user_data   = "d54655a7756575775f42548868" -> (known after apply) #forces replacement  
    
      - launch_template {# forces replacement
          - id  = "lt-0232332a4645b24" -> null
          - name = "dtt_app_server" -> null
        }
```

I tried using:

```
lifecycle {
   ignore_changes = [ user_data ]
}
```

in my resource file (.tf) and it worked for `user_data` in removing forced replacement.

How can I remove forced replacement for launch template?

I don't want to use lifecycle ignore_changes = all as it will ignore all the attributes.

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanx

Comment: Why not assign the current `user_data` value for those two instance to avoid the recreation?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. If  I assign the user_data value for the two instances, only the user_data force replacement message is disappearing but the launch_template {# force replacement is still on causing the instances to drop and recreate. Do you know how to get rid of launch_template (# force replacement) message in plan. please let me know.

Comment: If those two instances were created from a launch template, does that imply they originated from an autoscaling group?

Comment: No, they are not originated from autoscaling group.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to [import the existing launch template](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/launch_template#import)?

E.g. something like:

```sh
terraform import module.mymodule.aws_launch_template.mypet lt-0232332a4645b24
```

Then you need to make your code use the template as well (See [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance#launch_template)).

Comment: Hi mhvelplund, the above suggestions are helpful... Thanks.

Comment: @PrakashS if you think so, then upvote the answer ;)